# Arquivo settings.xml do Maven não encontrado

Tags: maven, jboss, wildfly

Estou acompanhando o seguinte artigo: [JBOSS/WILDFLY maven plugin para deploy LOCALHOST/REMOTE server](http://clairtonluz.github.io/blog/2014/07/2014070798.html).

Quero implementar isso no projeto que tenho aqui para fazer integração continua, testes utilizando o Maven, contudo não consigo encontrar essa pasta `.m2` que esta mencionando ou o arquivo `settings.xml`, não consigo localizar os mesmos, como posso proceder para implementar isso?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>wildfly-remote</id>
            <properties>
                <wildfly-hostname>192.168.0.123</wildfly-hostname>
                <wildfly-port>9990</wildfly-port>
                <wildfly-username>remoteuser</wildfly-username>
                <wildfly-password>remotepassword</wildfly-password>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>wildfly-local</id>
            <properties>
                <wildfly-home>${env.WILDFLY_HOME}</wildfly-home>
                <wildfly-hostname>127.0.0.1</wildfly-hostname>
                <wildfly-port>9990</wildfly-port>
                <wildfly-username>clairton</wildfly-username>
                <wildfly-password>localpassword</wildfly-password>
            </properties>
        </profile>

    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>wildfly-local</activeProfile>
        <activeProfile>wildfly-remote</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está o diretório padrão:
Assumindo que você utiliza `Windows`

```
C:\Documents and Settings\{usuario}\.m2
```

> Também pode ficar nessa pasta:

```
${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml
```